# error: cannot find symbol in PytorchDemoApp

Tags: java, android

I am not Android developer, I am just trying to deploy a demo app of [object detection](https://github.com/pytorch/android-demo-app/tree/master/ObjectDetection) in android and everything seems to go well while "make project" in Android Studio, but when I am trying to export the ".APK" file I get the following error

```
... AbstractCameraXActivity.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysisConfig;
                           ^
  symbol:   class ImageAnalysisConfig
  location: package androidx.camera.core
Tha same happens with other package which is PreviewConfig.
```

Both errors are marked in the [AbstractCameraXActivity.java](https://github.com/pytorch/android-demo-app/blob/master/ObjectDetection/app/src/main/java/org/pytorch/demo/objectdetection/AbstractCameraXActivity.java) file. And due to I am not Android developer, I don't know how to debug and solve this issue.

I know this could be better to ask in the issue's repo, but I think this is an error related with import package so maybe another Android/Java developer can help me.

Somebody knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't find the class you're looking for; https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/package-summary

Comment: Hi @HenryTwist (nice name), I finally solved using an old version of the NDK of android studio, because you right, it seems there's no that package in the last NDK. Thanks for your reply.